# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (37800, 10, 10)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I'm a beginner at machine learning. I am working on mnist dataset which I downloaded from kaggle. I am making this very first project by the help of a tutorial. But I'm facing this issue which I am unable to resolve. Please help. Here's the below.

```
import keras 
import keras.preprocessing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

X = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\faizan\Desktop\ML\Kaggle\MNIST\train.csv')

Y = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\faizan\Desktop\ML\Kaggle\MNIST\test.csv')

y = X["label"]

X = X.drop(["label"], 1)
#x = Y.drop(['label'], 1)

print(y.shape)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes = 10)
X = X / 255.0
X = X.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
# Shuffle Split Train and Test from original dataset
seed=2
train_index, valid_index = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1,
                                        train_size=0.9,
                                        test_size=None,
                                        random_state=seed).split(X).__next__()
x_train = X[train_index]
Y_train = y[train_index]
x_test = X[valid_index]
Y_test = y[valid_index]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=128,activation="relu", input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(Dense(units=128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation="softmax"))

## Compiling Model
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(0.001),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])


## Training

model.fit(x_train,Y_train,batch_size=32, epochs=10,verbose=1)
accuracy = model.evaluate(x=x_test, y=Y_test, batch_size=32)

## Checking Accuracy
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy[1])
```

Comment: Can you share more details about the error? Where does it happen? on compile? on fit? or on evaluation?

Comment: well from the error i guess the error is here `model.add(Dense(units=10,activation="softmax"))` and is caused by a shape of the target (y) different than expected due to the input shape and the use of dense layers for pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You are making some mistake that cause your network to fail.

First i will assume you are working with NMIST data set and that you are trying to classify each image to a class. Your Network is the following:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       256       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 10)        1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 34,570
Trainable params: 34,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**So**: You have four dimensions at the output of the network. And that is not right for a classification task. If you add a Flatten Layer just before the last layer:

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       256       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       16512     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 100352)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1003530   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,036,810
Trainable params: 1,036,810
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

and here you see that we have the ten classes you wanted. And that you only have two dimensions: one for the batch size (None) and the other for the classes (10). For one sample it will be a vector of probabilities for every class summing to one due to the softmax activation (mutually exclusives classes)

Could you please try to run with the flatten to see if this was your issue.
Then I strongly advice you to look into dealing with images in Keras because the use of Dense layers here (adn only Dense) is not optimal (for example you can see [this Kaggle tuto](https://www.kaggle.com/adityaecdrid/mnist-with-keras-for-beginners-99457))